# How make query for getting some objects from many-to-many model, using EF core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I try to do it like this:

```
var articles = db.Articles.Include(at => at.ArticleTags)
                          .ThenInclude(t => t.Tag)
                          .ToList();

var articlesTag = articles.Where(a => a.ArticleTags.Tag.TagValue == "news").ToList();
```

But it dont work. Visual Studio does not see this expression "a.ArticleTags.Tag.TagValue". How can I do it right?

Here is the implementation of the classes used:

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TagValue { get; set; }
    public List<ArticleTag> ArticleTags { get; set; }
    public List<UserTag> UserTags { get; set; }

    public Tag()
    {
        ArticleTags = new List<ArticleTag>();
        UserTags = new List<UserTag>();
    }
}

public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public List<ArticleTag> ArticleTags { get; set; }

    public Article()
    {
        ArticleTags = new List<ArticleTag>();
    }
}

public class ArticleTag
{
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public Article Article { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically `Include` and `ThenInclude` only role is to tell EF to load those nested objects while asking for data from the database. It doesn't allow You just to ommit the fact that the `ArticleTag` is a list of objects and You need to use one of avaliable methods of such object. So in this case You want to apply `Find` to the `ArticleTag` list.

Edit:

See the complete example below. Note that by instructing EF about relationships between models it is not needed for me to even bother about including data (lat example).

Model creation:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().HasData(
                new Article { Id = 1, Summary = "Article summary 1", Title = "Article title 1" },
                new Article { Id = 2, Summary = "Article summary 2", Title = "Article title 2" },
                new Article { Id = 3, Summary = "Article summary 3", Title = "Article title 3" },
                new Article { Id = 4, Summary = "Article summary 4", Title = "Article title 4" },
                new Article { Id = 5, Summary = "Article summary 5", Title = "Article title 5" },
                new Article { Id = 6, Summary = "Article summary 6", Title = "Article title 6" });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().HasKey(a => a.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().HasMany(a => a.ArticleTags).WithOne(at => at.Article);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasData(
                new Tag { Id = 1, TagValue = "Tag 1" },
                new Tag { Id = 2, TagValue = "Tag 2" });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasKey(t => t.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasMany(t => t.ArticleTags).WithOne(at => at.Tag);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleTag>().HasData(
                new ArticleTag { ArticleId = 1, TagId = 1 },
                new ArticleTag { ArticleId = 2, TagId = 1 },
                new ArticleTag { ArticleId = 1, TagId = 2 },
                new ArticleTag { ArticleId = 2, TagId = 2 },
                new ArticleTag { ArticleId = 3, TagId = 1 },
                new ArticleTag { ArticleId = 4, TagId = 2 });

            modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleTag>().HasKey(at => new { at.ArticleId, at.TagId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleTag>().HasOne(at => at.Article).WithMany(a => a.ArticleTags);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleTag>().HasOne(at => at.Tag).WithMany(t => t.ArticleTags);

            // Tag 1: Article 1,2,3
            // Tag 2: Article 1,2,4
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

Controller:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            db.Database.EnsureCreated();
            var articles = db.Articles.Include(at => at.ArticleTags)
                          .ThenInclude(t => t.Tag);

            var articlesTag1 = articles.Where(a => a.ArticleTags.Any(at => at.Tag.TagValue == "Tag 1")).ToList();

            var articlesTag2 = articles.Where(a => a.ArticleTags.Any(at => at.Tag.TagValue == "Tag 2")).ToList();

            var articles1 = await db.ArticleTags.Include(at => at.Article)
                          .Include(at => at.Tag)
                          .Where(at => at.Tag.TagValue == "Tag 1").ToListAsync();

            var articles2 = await db.ArticleTags
                          .Where(at => at.Tag.TagValue == "Tag 2").ToListAsync();
            return View();
        }
```

As You can see You can make it far easier by starting from the middle table, not needed for including chain thst will drill for data.

Comment: Thanks. But I still did not understand how to get all the articles with the corresponding tag. You can give an example.

Comment: See the updated answer, I have created a complete example for You, checked only InMemory db.